# Оформление тега option

Tags: html, css

На странице есть выпадающий список

```
<div id="currency">
        <p>currencies: </p>

        <form action="" method="post" name="currency-select" >
        <select class="styled">
            <option value="">Us Dollar</option>
            <option value="">Us Dollar</option>
            <option value="">Us Dollar</option>
        </select>
        </form>
    </div> <!-- /currency-->
```

оформление внешнего вида списка задается при помощи [этого плагина](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)
не получается задать свои стили для тегов option
в стилях прописано

```
#currency option {
    color: #757575;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

с цветом срабатывает, с размером текста - нет. Подскажите, как это можно решить?

Comment: Задавайте font-size не option, а select.

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло))